# Stopping ScheduledExecutorService when button action is performed in the UI

Tags: java

I have created a `scheduledExecutorService` as below

```
ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    // do stuff
  }
}, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

I would like to stop service when stop button is clicked in the `UI` or `JSP`. Any help on this is so much appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by "stop", do you mean you want to pause the execution allowing for resuming at a later date, or completely stop the service and shut it down?

Answer (score 0):

## `ScheduledFuture::cancel`

When calling [`ScheduledExecutorService::scheduleAtFixedRate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,long,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)), you get back a [`ScheduledFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledFuture.html). Currently your code ignores that returned object, and drops it.

Change your code to  capture that scheduled future object.

```
ScheduledFuture future = exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(…
```

The [`ScheduledFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledFuture.html) has methods to [cancel](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel(boolean)) the task, and to ask if the task [is already cancelled](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#isCancelled()).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `shutdownNow()` method of the executor.

```
exec.shutdownNow();
exec.awaitTermination();
```

It does *almost* what you want. It does not stop the thread immediately (cause it's not safe). Instead it sets `isInterrupted()` flag notifying the running thread that is should stop. So, your `Runnable` has to check for that flag from time to time. And when it finds the flag is set, it should return from the `run()` method.

`exec.awaitTermination();` is waiting until the thread is stopped. After that line you may be sure that the thread has stopped execution.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class with a flag variable.
Check the value of that flag and stop the thread if needed.

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
   private AtomicBoolean running = new AtomicBoolean(true);

   public void run() {
       while (running.get()) {
          ...
       }
   }

   public void stopMe() {
      running.set(false);
   }
} 


ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
MyRunnable myRunnable = new MyRunnable();
exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(myRunnable, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

...
myRunnable.stopMe();
```

Note: use an [`AtomicBoolean`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html) so you are sure to not have a side effect setting and checking the value of `running` variable in a multithread environment:

> A boolean value that may be updated atomically.